# Only Publish a node in certain languages

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

In D8 I have a node with several translations - not all translations will be ready to publish at the same time. 
If I unpublish one translation it unpublishes all transaltions and default translation. Is this a bug or do I have an incorrect setting somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all lets make sure you have set up Drupal correctly:

- Do you have activated the core Content translation module
- Do you have activated the core Language module
- Do you have set up at least 2 or more languages (of course you have)
- Do you have set up detection and selection correctly (I think you have)
- Do you have set up content types correctly to allow multiple languages (sure otherwise it won't work)
- Now when you start to list your nodes in `content/admin` overview you should be able to select translate each node
- If you choose this and you **translate** it you should see the button below saying `translate and publish` which can be switched to `translate and unpublish` this selection
- if you choose the second your translation will not be published automatically. Violá

Hope it helps ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply @frank-theissner, What I see at is `save and keep unpublished (all languages)` Now I think I may have a wrong setting somewhere that could be causing the (all languages) settings to be the only options - any idea what it could be?

Comment: http://oi67.tinypic.com/11id6ah.jpg this is how it looks here. I'm wondering how it comes to the option to save all languages. Is there another module interfering this behaviour?

Comment: For step 5, make sure you set up the content types at /admin/config/regional/content-language, and make sure that all the fields, specifically including the publication status are marked as translatable.

Comment: @Berdir that was exactly my problem, I never had publish status set as translatable. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Berdir Thanks for the tip, that was also my issue